Client using websocket to not connecting
My client just shows the status as closed. My C# application is using websocket-sharp:
WebSocketServer mWebSocketServer;

try {
  // Creation of server, ipWebSocketAddr = "ws://192.168.5.73/posttest.html
  // mcintWebSocketPort = 443
  mWebSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(ipWebSocketAddr, mcintWebSocketPort);
  mWebSocketServer.AddWebSocketService<clsQuintexMsg>("/clsQuintexMsg");
} 
catch (Exception ex)  
{
  FrmMain.UpdateTaskbar(ex.ToString());
}

In my JavaScript:
try {
  webSocket = new WebSocket(cstrServerSocketIP);
  
  //Setup timeout timer to timeout if webSocket does not connect
  tmrCheckWebSocket = setInterval(function() {
    var strMsg = "Checking webSocket (" + cstrServerSocketIP + "), ";
    if (typeof webSocket == "object" &&
      typeof webSocket.readyState == "number") {
      if (webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
        strMsg += "connecting";
      } else if (webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
        strMsg += "open (connected)";
      } else if (webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.CLOSING) {
        strMsg += "closing";
      } else if (webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.CLOSED) {
        strMsg += "closed";
      }
    } else {
      strMsg += "not a valid websocket!";
    }
    DebugMsg(strMsg);
  }, cintCheckWebSocketInterval);
  
  webSocket.onclose = (event) => {
    var strReason = "";
    if (typeof event == "object") {
      if (typeof event.code == "number") {
        strReason += "code[" + event.code + "]";
        var strError = cobjWebSocketErrors[event.code];
        if (typeof strError == "string") {
          strReason += ":" + strError;
        }
      }
      if (typeof event.reason == "string" && event.reason.length > 0) {
        if (strReason.length > 0) {
          strReason += ", ";
        }
        strReason += "reason:\"" + event.reason + "\"";
      }
    }
    DebugMsg("webSocket.onclose " + strReason);
  };
  
  webSocket.onerror = (event) => {
    DebugMsg("webSocket.onerror" + ((typeof event == "object" && typeof event.data != "undefined") ? ":" + String(event.data) : ""));
  };
  
  webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
    DebugMsg("webSocket.onmessage");
    if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      console.lob("Received ArrayBuffer");
      console.lob(event.data);
    }
    webSocket.close();
  };
  
  webSocket.onopen = () => {
    DebugMsg("webSocket.onopen");
  };
  
  //Set-up timer to send requests for data updates
  InstallServiceTimer(cintServiceRequestInterval);
} catch (e) {
  DebugMsg(e);
}

Just found an exception is being thrown in c# application when calling  start:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=There is no server certificate for secure connection.
  Source=websocket-sharp
  StackTrace:
   at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.start()
   at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.Start()
   at CheetahCS.clsServer..ctor(String strRoot, String strDefault, Int32 intWWWPort, Int32 intWebSocketPort) in clsServer.cs:line 131

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.start()
    WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.Start()
    clsServer.clsServer(string, string, int, int) in clsServer.cs

Why does it think this is a secure connection?
It seems there is a bug in the WebSocketSharp code when passing the IPAddress and port seperately it defaults to a secure connection.  I changed the above to use a string with the prefix ws://address:443, now no exception.

Aside to the problem, but please do not use Hungarian notation in C# or JS code. Or ever, frankly.

@RoryMcCrossan, why not, give me a reason?  It makes looking at a screen of code very easy and removes the need to find the declarations to determine what types are used.

Well structured code will make datatypes clear, and a good IDE will also render it meaningless. Unless you're writing code in Notepad, HN is useless noise.

@RoryMcCrossan, I don't use Hungarian strictly, but a variant of it, using descriptive names makes perfect sense.

Normally 443 is the port for secure wss while ws should default to 80 (or 8080), not quite sure why it manifests like that though, but def shouldn't use 443 for this setup

I already have a web-server implementation in C# listening to port 80, I don't think I could use the same address and port for the websocket-sharp implementation could I?

I've changed the websocket server instance to listen on the same IP but port 8080, still no connection.

yes, you'll need to pick a different port in this case and specify it when connecting to your ws server. I'm also confused by your address setup, I think it should be smth like 0.0.0.0 (or IPAdress.Any) instead smth like ws://0.0.0.0:8080, maybe check more websocket-sharp samples; another hint there's a  wscat utility for communicating to ws from cli, useful for testing

The connection address is ws://192.168.5.7:8080
